# how to make a linear layout horizontall scrollable

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, horizontal-scrolling

My application containing different layouts.one of them is a linear layout.it's content is dynamically adding.i want to make this layout horizontally scrollable.for this i have put my layout in a scroll view.but still it s not scrolling...given below is my code

```
 <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/scoreballparent_layout"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_above="@+id/score_layout">
  <ScrollView android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:id="@+id/scrollView1" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  >
      <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:id="@+id/scoreball_layout" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:isScrollContainer="true" 
      android:scrollbars="horizontal">

         </LinearLayout>
     </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Take into account that if the content fits in the screen then the scroll bars will not appear.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [HorizontalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html) instead

Also your layout will become scrollabe after its contect can't fit layout area.

Comment: thanks...but 1 thing..it is showing scrollbar while scrolling.i dnt want to display that..and i want to automatically scroll the layout when adding new things to this layout..can u help me plz..

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this in xml
`android:fadeScrollbars="true"` may be it works for you